# TSQL - Delete All Rows Except 1 Per Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have 5 workcenters (Workcenter 1, Workcenter 2, Workcenter 3, Workcenter 4, Workcenter 5)

Each workcenter has several rows of notes that are ordered by the date the data was entered.  I would like to delete all rows per workcenter  except the row of data that was entered last.

If my columns are: ID | Workcenter | Note | Log_Date

How would I go about doing this?

My code is only giving me the most current note entry for the entire table, but I want one per workcenter.

This is what I have right now:

```
DELETE FROM @Table
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @Table 
             GROUP BY Workcenter, ID 
             ORDER BY Log_Date DESC)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
delete t1 from table t1 
where not exists
(select 1 from 
       (select workcenter,max(log_date)as log_date from table group by workcenter) t2  
       where t1.workcenter = t2.workcenter and t1.log_date = t2.log_date
)
```

use exists subquery to get the max log_date for each workcenter and then connect them to the table.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
using CTE we can achieve this:

;WITH cte AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY createdate DESC ) AS rowno, * FROM workgroups)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE rowno !=1;

CREATE TABLE workgroups(id INT IDENTITY(1,1),name VARCHAR(50), createdate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE())

INSERT [dbo].[workgroups] ([id], [name], [createdate]) VALUES (1, N'workgroup1', CAST(0x0000A60F011F7840 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[workgroups] ([id], [name], [createdate]) VALUES (2, N'workgroup1', CAST(0x0000A60F011F7F8E AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[workgroups] ([id], [name], [createdate]) VALUES (3, N'workgroup1', CAST(0x0000A60F011F8728 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[workgroups] ([id], [name], [createdate]) VALUES (4, N'workgroup2', CAST(0x0000A60F011F92B9 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[workgroups] ([id], [name], [createdate]) VALUES (5, N'workgroup2', CAST(0x0000A60F011F97C0 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[workgroups] ([id], [name], [createdate]) VALUES (6, N'workgroup3', CAST(0x0000A60F011FA443 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[workgroups] ([id], [name], [createdate]) VALUES (7, N'workgroup3', CAST(0x0000A60F011FA73B AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[workgroups] ([id], [name], [createdate]) VALUES (8, N'workgroup3', CAST(0x0000A60F011FA9FB AS DateTime))

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY createdate DESC ) AS rowno, * FROM workgroups


;WITH cte AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY createdate DESC ) AS rowno, * FROM workgroups)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE rowno !=1;
```